# How to get the accuracy distance in GoogleMaps Api for Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to detect the coordinates of some markers based on current location, but my problem is, sometimes, the accuracy range circle of my current position is relatively large and i have very difficulty to detect those markers because my current location is a little far from the markers. My question is if there is someway to check if the coordinates of those markers are inside the accuracy circle of my current position, or to get the radius distance of the circle?

Comment: I believe the *coordinates* of markers are static and not based on a users location. Please edit your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

`Accuracy` parameter is precisely the radius of a confidence circle. From Android doc:

> We define accuracy as the radius of 68% confidence. In other words, if
>   you draw a circle centered at this location's latitude and longitude,
>   and with a radius equal to the accuracy, then there is a 68%
>   probability that the true location is inside the circle.

You can also get distance between two GoogleMap Point doing this:

```
Location location1 = new Location(point1.latitude, point1.longitude);
Location location2 = new Location(point2.latitude, point2.longitude);
float distanceInMeters = location1.distanceTo(location2);
```

Comment: I'm assuming the 68% confidence is due to the inaccuracy/fluctuations of the GPS hardware? Especially when indoors.

Comment: Probably, but you can get a pretty good accuracy when doing several location request. And if it bothers you to do so, you can use **Google API Location Services** which do everything automatically.